# Difference between defining expression via parse or expression

Tags: r, parsing, expression

`parse` is a function that returns expressions. Doing

```
parse(text = "print('hey')")
```

returns

```
expression(print('hey'))
```

One can also identify an expression by doing

```
expression(print('hey'))
```

Slightly surprisingly the output of this is

```
expression(print("hey"))
```

Note the change in double quotes. But this is not the only difference. Passing `parse(text = "print('hey')")` to `getParseData` has a different output than passing `expression(print('hey'))`.

```
getParseData(parse(text = "print('hey')"))

line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent                token terminal  text
9     1    1     1   12  9      0                 expr    FALSE      
1     1    1     1    5  1      3 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE print
3     1    1     1    5  3      9                 expr    FALSE      
2     1    6     1    6  2      9                  '('     TRUE     (
4     1    7     1   11  4      6            STR_CONST     TRUE 'hey'
6     1    7     1   11  6      9                 expr    FALSE      
5     1   12     1   12  5      9                  ')'     TRUE     )
```

while

```
getParseData(expression(print('hey')))

NULL
```

I am unsure what the difference between these two outputs and I would very much like to know.

Another point is (which will probably be asked as a separate question once this is answered) that `parse` isn't even consistent in returning 'parse-able' output. I first realised a difference exists when I tested a function that uses `parse` in Rstudio's testing environment that calls `devtools::test`. There, `parse(text = expression(print('hey')))` returned the double quoted output `expression(print("hey"))` which returns NULL when passed to `getParseData`

Comment: So is the question just why `expression(print('hey'))` changes the quotes to double quotes? I'm not surprised that `getParseData()` doesn't return information from things not run through `parse()` -- it doesn't have any of that line and column information at it's disposal. Perhaps you could ask an explicit question here?

Comment: The exact question is what is the difference between the outputs. The line-column information you mentioned for instance. How can I diagnose it's absence or presence from the output (other than trying to parse it) as visually the two outputs look rather similar.

Comment: If you have `a<-parse(text = "print('hey')"); b<-expression(print('hey'))` compare their structure with `str(a); str(b);` You can see they are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is only in the attributes. If you remove the attributes from the parsed version then they are identical:

```
p <- parse(text = "print('hey')")
attributes(p) <- NULL

e <- expression(print('hey'))

identical(p, e)
## [1] TRUE
```